# Oracle SQL - How to do massive updates more efficient and faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, updates, updating

I'm trying to update 500.000 rows at once. I have a table with products like this:

```
+------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| PRODUCT_ID | SUB_PRODUCT_ID | DESCRIPTION  | CLASS |
+------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| A001       | ACC1           | coffeemaker  | A     |
| A002       | ACC1           | toaster      | A     |
| A003       | ACC2           | coffee table | A     |
| A004       | ACC5           | couch        | A     |
+------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

I've sets of individually statements, for example:

```
update products set class = 'A' where product_id = 'A001';
update products set class = 'B' where product_id = 'A005';
update products set class = 'Z' where product_id = 'A150';
```

I'm making a query putting one update statement below the other update statement and putting a commit statement each 1.000 rows. 
It works fine (slow, but fine) but I wanna do it better if it can be possible in any way.

There is a better way to do this more efficient and faster?

Comment: How many total rows in the table? 
What indexes do you have? 
Are they (table and index) partitioned? 
Are the stats on the table and indexes up-to-date?
What is primary key on the table?

Comment: Hi @Vampiro ! 
How many total rows in the table? 980.000 aproximadetly 
What indexes do you have? PRODUCT_ID (is PK) and SUB_PRODUCT_ID
Are they (table and index) partitioned? Are the stats on the table and indexes up-to-date? I believe, but I don't know it exactly (sorry for this answer). I do not admin this table really, I only can make DML statements on it.
What is primary key on the table? PRODUCT_ID

Comment: Where does the data for your `update` statements come from?  It seems likely that the new `class` values are stored somewhere other than a file of SQL statements.  If they are in a table, you want to do a single set-based correlated update.  If they are in a file, you want to load that file, potentially via an external table, and do a single set-based correlated update.

Comment: As you're modifying a huge amount of data, more than 50%, it's better to avoid individual updates. See if you can rewrite the logic to do the update in bulk. Also do partition the tackle and index as hash partitions, that will definitely help.

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"? Do you want faster or more efficent? (They're not the same thing) what is the table structure? Where is your explain plan? How many records are in the table? How is it indexed? Do you need the operation to be concurrent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to create a temporary table holding your update information:

**new_product_class**:

```
product_id  class
==========  =====
A           A001
B           A005
Z           A150
```

`product_id` should be an indexed primary key on this new table.  Then you can do an `UPDATE` or a `MERGE` on the old table joined to this temporary table:

```
UPDATE (SELECT p.product_id, p.class, n.product_id, n.class
          FROM product p
          JOIN new_product_class n ON (p.product_id = n.product_id)
  SET p.class = n.class
```

or

```
MERGE INTO product p
  USING new_product_class n
  ON (p.product_id = n.product_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET p.class = n.class
```

Merge should be fast. Other things that you could look into depending on your environment: create a new table based on the old table with `nologging` followed by some renaming (should backup before and after), bulk updates.

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm late to coment this. Thank you @Glenn!. Temporary table was the solution. Really fast way using MERGE.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have an index, each of your update statements scans the entire table.  Even if you do have an index, there is a cost associated with the compilation and execution of each statement.

If you have a lot of conditions, and those conditions can vary, then I think Glenn's solution is clearly the way to go.  This does everything in a single transaction, and there is no reason to run batches of 1,000 rows -- just do everything all at once.

If the number of conditions is relatively finite (as your example), and they don't change very often, then you can also do this as a simple case:

```
update products
set class =
  case product_id
    when 'A001' then 'A'
    when 'A005' then 'B'
    when 'A150' then 'C'
  end
where
  product_id in ('A001', 'A005', 'A150')
```

If it's possible your `class` field is already set to the correct value, then there is also great value in adding a condition to make sure you are not updating something to the same value.  For example if this:

```
update products set class = 'A' where product_id = 'A001';
```

Updates 5,000 records, 4,000 of which are already set to 'A', then this would be significantly more efficient:

```
update products
set class = 'A'
where
  product_id = 'A001' and
 (class is null or class != 'A')
```